# Рекурсия рефералов на PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, рекурсия

Прошу момощи просить массив на php с рефералами вида

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 5
        ),
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 7
        ),
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
        ),
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )
)
```

Будет 4 уровня (уровень 1 ключ массива)

Код

```
//Рекурсия
function get_refs($user, $level, $data = array()) {
    //Получим список реферов пользоваптеля
    $row = db_get_array("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `ref` = '$user' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    //Если есть результат
    if ($row) {
        //Цикл
        foreach ($row as $ref) {
            //Добавим в массив
            $data[$level][] = $ref["id"];
            //Вызовем функцию
            $data[$level] = get_refs($ref["id"], $level, $data);
        }
    }
    $level++;
    return $data;
}
```

Таблица MySQL 5.1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `ref`, `login`) VALUES
    (3, 2, 'user'),
    (5, 3, 'user2'),
    (6, 3, 'user3'),
    (7, 6, 'user4'),
    (8, 6, 'user5'),
    (9, 7, 'user6'),
    (10, 9, 'user7');
```

Comment: Клёво... а чего надо-то? вопрос в чём?

Comment: Как построить массив который указан сначала.

Comment: Укажите точную версию MySQL. Уберите фотографию таблицы. Выложите её CREATE TABLE и INSERT INTO с примером данных (как указали - 4 уровня). Покажите требуемый результат на именно этих данных. Рекурсия на PHP лишняя - указанный массив можно получить прямо в MySQL, скажем, в виде вложенного JSON-массива (и не придётся сервер тыщу раз дёргать).

Comment: Добавил таблицу и insert.

Comment: Осталось "Укажите точную версию MySQL" и "Покажите требуемый (полностью!) результат на именно этих данных".

Comment: поправил, добавил массив с результатом и версию MySQL

Comment: Посмотрел скрипт - вижу 5 уровней.

Answer (score 1):

> MySQL 5.1

Какая однако седая древность... для неё только разве что

```sql
SELECT 1 AS level, id
FROM users t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM users t0
                   WHERE t0.id = t1.ref )
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, t2.id
FROM users t1
JOIN users t2 ON t1.id = t2.ref
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM users t0
                   WHERE t0.id = t1.ref )
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, t3.id
FROM users t1
JOIN users t2 ON t1.id = t2.ref
JOIN users t3 ON t2.id = t3.ref
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM users t0
                   WHERE t0.id = t1.ref )
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, t4.id
FROM users t1
JOIN users t2 ON t1.id = t2.ref
JOIN users t3 ON t2.id = t3.ref
JOIN users t4 ON t3.id = t4.ref
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM users t0
                   WHERE t0.id = t1.ref )
ORDER BY level, id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ebc3fb425e4812bc7e618e99b9473b7)

Можно получать данные отдельными запросами, можно все 4 уровня сразу объединяющим запросом, а можно и сразу все кусты финальным запросом.

На PHP осталось получить что-то из указанного (отдельные уровни в 4 запроса, всё кучей и т.п.) и конвертировать полученный набор записей в требуемую структуру (не думаю. что это зело сложно).